# Can Ticks be ticked at different speed depending on computer?

Tags: c#, timer

I created an App which uses Timer class to callback a method at a certain time of a day and recall it every 24 hours after that.

I use Ticks to signify 24 hours later. `(int) TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds`
I use that to retrieve the ticks for 24 hours.

This works fine for me but on different computers, the trigger time is way off.

Anyway to debug this ? How should I fight/handle this issue ....

Comment: I don't see you using ticks in the code posted up there. Also, what do you mean by "way off"? What is an acceptable tolerance for your purposes?

Comment: Scheduling isn't a trivial feature. Windows has the built in Schedule Task feature, which would probably be a better way to do your scheduling. This still does not mean it would run exactly the same on all machines, though - clocks by default will not stay in perfect sync.

Comment: @ananthonline, That is my ticks as you convert it to int you would get 86400000, tolerance by minutes not hours... Way off by 6 hours minimum.

Comment: @PaulPhillips, Scheduling is great but my Application is running 24/7 with other functionality, so scheduling will not be possible unless it can trigger a certain method in the application. Also, I know computer to computer timers are different but 6 hour fluctuation is outrageous. :)

Comment: Please show us a short but complete example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TimS., Someone sets a timer for 6 am every morning. Now every morning at 6 am it will do something. On the several computers I have this does it on time. but on my client PC it will deviate to 2 pm... which is horrible. Now I believe, it is caused by some type of issue that holds the timer for some reason or the other but I have no clue how to debug it.... I can post code but it be useless. It's a simple Timer class that I am using.

Comment: I think your problem lies in the `(int)` cast. Your ticks value is probably rolling over if you're casting it to an int.

Comment: @Chris, I logged the Ticks values before I set the Timer. Well anyway, It's all right guys I will figure it out during the weekend. If anyone want to still answer, please focus on showing me a way to debug a Timer or gather information from it over time. Thank you !

Comment: Do you have the availability to query an outside NTP server for the time, and ignore local system time?

Comment: @PaulPhillips is right, you should use Scheduled Tasks, if at all possible.

Comment: @Chris: 24 hours in milliseconds (86.4 million) fits within an int easily (+/-2.1 billion).  As long as you're not trying to sum those over a period of weeks, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much is "way off" to you? If you want an app to run at a specific time, schedule it for that specific time, not 24 hours from the time it finishes - you're inevitably going to see some slippage doing it that way because the time will always be off the next day X seconds, where X is how long the program took to complete the previous day.

Comment: 6 hours off in lucky cases and the app is always running so a scheduler which calls an app is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

How "way off" yes desktop computers clocks frequently fluctuate by a second or more every day, they generally use a NTP server to correct these fluctuations. But its just the nature of the beast.

Comment: fluctuates by a couple hours if lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no "my ticks" because a Tick is a well-defined value.

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

A DateTime object also has a [Ticks property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) that you can use to access it. I wrote some simple code that I've posted [here](http://pastebin.com/gbDhQUhc) worked great for me, producing [perfect results](http://pastebin.com/aiCEaYpi).

I see no reason your implementation should drift so much. Please make a sample that consistently produces the problem or post the relevant pieces of your own source.